# PTIJ: Looking for other holiday cookbooks

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am looking for cookbooks that explore the recipes for the foods associated with different holidays. I have just finished my Channukah selection, the חובות הלביבות and am going to start the text with instructions how to make food for Pesach, מצות עשה (not the version specific to grandmothers). I am [not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111508/ptij-why-must-tofu-products-be-baked) linking to the vegetarian cookbook as that food is not associated with a holiday. Or happiness. Or anything good.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You say it's not the version specific to grandmothers, but there's three volumes of the grandmothers' cookbook: בבא קמא, בבא מציעא, ובבא בתרא

Comment: @DonielF this is true, but I'm not looking for any that are Zman Grandma

Comment: [tag:purim-torah-ingest]

Comment: @msh210 h/t Rabbi Ham-let

Answer (score 10):

Here are my go-to recipe books for all the major holidays of the Jewish year:

- Every participant at the **Pesach** Seder [needs to drink four cups of wine](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.1?lang=bi). Choosing good-quality wines without breaking the bank can be difficult. [R. Moses Isserles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles)' guide **[*The Price of Wine*](https://hebrewbooks.org/40161)** is an invaluable resource. (It also comes in handy during the Purim season.)
- **Shavu'ot** is the [festival of the wheat harvest](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.22?lang=bi). There is also a longstanding custom [to eat dairy foods](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.494.3?lang=bi) during this holiday. I like to combine both of these elements using recipes found in [R. Isaac Hai Taib](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91)'s ***[Milk and Wheat](https://hebrewbooks.org/37312)***.
- The pre-**Tish'ah BeAv** meal [traditionally incorporates eggs](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.552.5?lang=bi). But how should the eggs be served? Fortunately, there's **[an entire Talmudic tractate](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=2&format=pdf)** on the topic.
- Many have the custom to [have new fruits on the second night](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.600.2?lang=bi) of **Rosh HaShanah**. I often get some ideas from [R. Hezekiah da Silva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah_da_Silva)'s ***[New Fruit](https://hebrewbooks.org/19333)***.
- Planning the menu for the pre-**Yom Kipur** *seudah hamafseket* can sometimes be a little tricky. I like to get inspiration from [R. Abraham Maimonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Maimonides)' [***HaMafsik LeOvdei Hashem***](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=159024&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=1) ('The Concluding Meal for Those who Serve G-d').
- Thinking of taking a day trip on Hol HaMoed of **Sukkot**? What should you bring for a picnic lunch? Try consulting ***[Food for the Journey](https://hebrewbooks.org/14130)*** by [R. Menahem ibn Zerah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97).
- As you alluded to in your question, **Hannukah** is the holiday of oil-frying. But what oil is best used for which foods? **[*The Good Oil*](https://hebrewbooks.org/50691)** by [R. Shmelke of Nikolsburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmelke_of_Nikolsburg) is a great resource.
- **Tu BiShvat** is, of course, the time to eat fruits. Many wonderful ideas can be found in **[*Delectable Fruits*](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Megadim_on_Yoreh_De'ah%2C_Mishbezot_Zahav.1.1?lang=bi)** by [R. Joseph Teomim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Meir_Teomim).
- On **Purim**, many eat triangular [*hamantaschen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamantash). I like to take this custom one step further and (referencing [Psalm 22](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.22.1?lang=bi) and [its connection to Purim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111609/connection-between-tehillim-22-and-purim)) serve triangular [venison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venison). I follow the recipe of [R. Elijah of Vilna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) in his **[*The Three-Cornered Stag*](https://hebrewbooks.org/20713)**.

***Betei'avon!***

Comment: these are great! I can add them to my confectionery work for the feast of Tabernacles, Noy Sucker, and the large collection https://imgur.com/a/uPS7FiW

Comment: -slow clap- Well done.

Comment: @DonielF Glad you enjoyed

Answer (score 5):

I recommend Taaruvos, a Spanish cookbook by J. Karo. Inside you can except to find all sorts of fascinating recipes - for both the beginner and the advanced.

Although it was not written for this purpose, it is in fact the perfect purim cookbook!

Comment: Subtitled: How to halachically eat treif food - with pictures!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the שולחן ערוך's English version called "The Prepared Table". It is a wonderful book filled with quick recipes as well as ideas for how to set your table for various occasions - holidays, vorts, LeChaim's, *shvigger's* (mother-in-law) visits, and more. I will warn you that it comes in five hefty volumes, so you better be prepared to do a lot of learning and cooking.

There is an abbreviation version called "The Tour of the Prepared Table", which you may want to browse first.

Comment: I hear it’s great for the spirit and soul!

Comment: I hear that fifth volume is [awfully obscure](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89391/).

Comment: @DonielF Go figure! I unintentionally alluded to something in my answer! Thanks for reminding me. It makes my answer even better, now!